# Robolectric Unit Testing Sugar ORM

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, sugarorm

I'm new with unit testing, even newer with Robolectric.
Now, I'm trying to run Robolectric testing with Sugar ORM, but keep getting this message

```
objc[535]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61500', transport: 'socket'
No such manifest file: /Users/virginia/Documents/Android%20Developer/ravnandroid_v5/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
meta data -> {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: SugarContext has not been initialized properly. Call SugarContext.init(Context) in your Application.onCreate() method and SugarContext.terminate() in your Application.onTerminate() method.

    at com.orm.SugarContext.getSugarContext(SugarContext.java:24)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:360)
    at com.orm.TestSugarApp.insertUserTest(TestSugarApp.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [...]

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61500', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 255
```

This is my **graddle** dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2"
```

Test Class

```
package com.orm;

@RunWith(CustomRoboelectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config( constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23)
public class TestSugarApp {

    @Test
    public void startEverTestSugarAppAsFirst() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void insertUserTest() {
        DBRavnUser user = new DBRavnUser("8099999999", "Sample User");
        long id = user.save();
        assertEquals(id > 0, id);
    }
}
```

This, my RobolectricGradleTestRunner extension:

```
public class CustomRoboelectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {
    public CustomRoboelectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        String buildVariant = (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty()
                ? "" : BuildConfig.FLAVOR+ "/") + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
        String intermediatesPath = BuildConfig.class.getResource("")
                .toString().replace("file:", "");
        intermediatesPath = intermediatesPath.substring(0, intermediatesPath.indexOf("/classes"));

        System.setProperty("android.package",
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        System.setProperty("android.manifest",
                intermediatesPath + "/manifests/full/" + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
        System.setProperty("android.resources", intermediatesPath + "/res/merged/" + buildVariant);
        System.setProperty("android.assets", intermediatesPath + "/assets/" + buildVariant);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {

        String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
        String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
        String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
        AndroidManifest manifest = new AndroidManifest(
                Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty),
                Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty)) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getApplicationMetaData() {
                Map<String, Object> metadata =  super.getApplicationMetaData();
                metadata.put("DATABASE", "rcn.db");
                metadata.put("VERSION", "16");
                metadata.put("QUERY_LOG", "false");
                metadata.put("DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
                return metadata;
            }
        };
        manifest.setPackageName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        return manifest;
    }
}
```

As you see here, I'm overriding `getApplicationMetaData` to setup SugarORM metadata info.

Any help in the correct direction will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Call SugarContext.init(Context) in your Application.onCreate() method and SugarContext.terminate() in your Application.onTerminate() method

This error message already tell you what to do. Instead of your application class you can add this both method calls at start and end of your test.

Answer (score 0):

This method won't be called in any real Android device. This method is used purely in emulated process environments such as an emulator

Answer (score 0):

I used your `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` and was able to make it work by adding this:

```
@Before
public void setupFromBase() {
    SugarOrm.init(Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class)
            .create()
            .resume()
            .get());
}

@After
public void cleanupFromBase() {
    SugarOrm.terminate();
}
```